# mern - updated values are null in data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I'm trying to update the posts. The PUT request in the back end works fine, returning 200 and updates posts when tested on Postman however when I try to update a post in the front end (react), I'm not receiving any errors but the updated post isn't being updated on submit and **the updated fields (title and body) are null.** The updated values are null when I `console.log(data)` in the front end which is why they aren't being sent to the back end but they are shown correctly in `post`.
Why are the updated values `null` inside `data`? How can I update the post with the new values instead of getting null?

`data:`
[image: data]
`post:`
[image: post]
Updated code: Frontend

```
const EditPost = ({match}) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    title: "",
    body: "",
    error: ""
  });
  
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});
  const { user, token } = isAuthenticated();
  const {
    title,
    body,
    error,
  } = values;


  const init = (id) => { 
      read(id).then(data => {
if (data.error) {
    setValues({...values, error: data.error})
} else {
    setValues({...values,
         title: data.title,
        body: data.body,
    }) 
    setPost({title: values.title, body: values.body})
     }
    })
}
 

useEffect(() => {
    const id = match.params.id;
  init(id);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  setPost({...values });
}, [values.title, values.body]);


  const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const clickSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, error: "" });

    editPost(match.params.userId, match.params.id, token, post).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
      } else {
        setValues({
          ...values,
          title: "",
          body: "",
          error: false,
        });      
      console.log(post)
      console.log(data)
      }
    });
  };

  const newPostForm = () => (
    <form onSubmit={clickSubmit}>
      <div>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange("title")} type="text"
          name="title"
          value={title}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <textarea
          onChange={handleChange("body")}
          value={body} name="body"
        />
      </div>

      <button type="submit">Publish</button>
    </form>
  );
  const showError = () => (
    <div
      style={{ display: error ? "" : "none" }}>
      {error}
    </div>
  );

  return (
        <div>  
          {showError()}
          {newPostForm()}
        </div>
  );
};

export default EditPost;
```

```
export const editPost = (userId, id, token, post) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/${userId}/${id}/edit`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(post)
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
            
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

postsByUser.js

```
 <Link className="mypost_btn edit_btn" to={`/${_id}/${post._id}/edit`}>
     Edit
 </Link>
```

Backend code

```
exports.edit = (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
        return res.status(400).send(`ID is not valid: ${req.params.id}`)

  const {title, body} = req.body

  const updatedPost = {title, body }

  Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    $set: updatedPost
  }, {new:true}, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return error
    } else {
      res.send(data)
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: data is coming from read, so that is where your problem is, but we don't have the backend code which must be where the issue is because it's not returning the data.

Comment: Okay thank you, I've added the code!  @7iiBob

Comment: When you check in your state do you see the values?

Comment: Can you confirm that `console.log()` inside of `exports.edit` does print out the data that is sent to response object?

Comment: @Rahni,
Can you please check what do you get in response? I believe the response itself is in json, there is no need to convert it to json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
editPost(match.params.userId, match.params.id, token, post)
```

> `post` is not defined.

Since `post` is not defined, no data is passed. Hence `title` and `body` equal to `null`. What you will need to do is, assuming from what I'm seeing on your code, is to define a state variable called `post`. I think you intended to do that:

```
const [post, setPost] = useState({values.title, values.body});
```

Then ensure that your post is updated whenever your `values` change using `useEffect()`,

```
useEffect(() => {
   setPost({...values });
}, [values.title, value.body]);
```

So by the time you call your `editPost()` http-put-method, then post has a `value`. And it should work.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. It has helped a lot and I'm now getting the values for the title and body on `post` although `data` is still returning null for the updated values. Basically, `post` only contains the values in the state (title, body and error) whereas `data` contains the whole post.

Comment: Atleast we're getting closer... Can you please `console.log(updatedPost )` in your server and see if `title` and `body` is indeed received by the server end? It's clear that they are set and sent from the front-end side but the behavior shows that they aren't being saved if they return null. Please console log and let me know of what happens?

Comment: I have `console.log(updatedPost)` and the values are undefined.  I get `{ title: undefined, body: undefined }}`  @MosiaThabo

Comment: Then they are not passed to the BackEnd, or they're not being binded correctly. All you need to do is make sure they are going to the backend. I think that's the only problem currently.

Comment: I've just worked out the last problem. I forgot to add `"Content-Type": "application/json"` as a header in my API request. Thanks for your answer! @MosiaThabo

Comment: Damn... And can I tell you that I saw that earlier. And Somehow, I went further and searched for ` Accept: 'application/json'` and realized it's also used by a lot of people so I ended up not paying attention to it, lol! Yah! The little things are the ones that make our code not to work somehow. But I am happy that you managed to get your code to work. Atleast now you can focus on other important things on your project. Good Luck @Rahni

Comment: Definitely, these little problems/errors are what make a feature take so much longer than they would otherwise have taken but I'm so pleased to finally have this edit post feature working. On to the next problem to solve :) Thank you! @MosiaThabo

Answer (score 1):

in EditPost.js `editPost(match.params.userId, match.params.id, token).then((data) => {` here you are missing the 4th arg which is the "post" it self you send to be updated

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added `post` as an argument but still when I `console.log(data)`, I'm receiving null for title and body fields. I tried setting the state for post but I can't seem to get it to work. @AlyAbdElRahman

Comment: I would console.log id on the backend inside readById and check the terminal and make sure that id is making it through. Are you sure that the post is being created from the start?

Comment: Yes, the post is definitely being created and readById also works. I have `console.log(id)` in `readById` and `edit` and they're both correct. @7iiBob

Comment: @Rahni could you please update the code in EditPost.js `editPost`, so that we can see how you send the post data ?